# Can different (though identical) structs be accessed as equals, without shared protocol-variables?

Tags: ios

I am using some auto-generated code for my project.
In these files, some of the created structs are literally identical, though have different names. As a simple example, let's say they look like this:

```
struct FromPlace:CoreClass{
    let id:String
    let name:String
}
struct ToPlace:CoreClass{
    let id:String
    let name:String
}
```

Yes yes, I know, there should only exist *one* `struct Place:CoreClass`. I don't have any choice in the matter, as this code is automatically generated far far away. Just humour me in figuring this out, will you?:)

The `CoreClass` is something they have in common, but has little to do with this.

I also can't change the file. It is locked. And no, I don't want to unlock it.

Let's say I have my own class, named `AwesomePlace`. I'd like to initialise my awesome place with any other place, like this:

```
class AwesomePlace{
    init(place:FromPlaceOrToPlace){
        //Be able to write place.id or place.name here pls
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to send an instance of FromPlace or ToPlace to this init, which retains the possibility to access their correct variables. And since the other codes are auto-generated, I need this to be automatic based on the variables in the structs, no manual middle-man.

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
protocol FromPlaceOrToPlace {}
extension FromPlace:FromPlaceOrToPlace{}
extension ToPlace:FromPlaceOrToPlace{}
```

but in doing this, I lose the ability to access any variables in `FromPlaceOrToPlace`, because it doesn't have any. To "fix" this, I could insert the common variables in the protocol, but I don't want to do that. I can't have any manual work here. These autogenerated codes will potentially change quite often.

You see where I'm going? Is such a thing possible, without me having to fill in the common variables in the protocol, as one usually would do?

Can I for example somehow create a protocol that **inherits from** `FromPlace`, and then create an extension for `ToPlace` which inherits this? Using one of them as "base" for the common "protocol"(or whatever) is okay, if possible.

Comment: If the autogenerated codes change often, so will the code in `AwesomePlace.init()`, right? And if there is a common subset that this `init` can rely on, it doesn't hurt to write it once in a `AnyPlace` protocol...

Comment: @Gereon I guess you're right.. I was just hoping there was a way to get around this without doing any of it manually. In my actual situation, there are *a lot* of variables in these `Place`-structs. Many of them are nested structs that are also based on the same auto-generation-logic, with same content and different name. I'd have to do this logic for a lot of structs, which makes me kinda sad since the objects are automatically generated in the first place. I was hoping to make it completely automatic. It's either this, or create one init each, I guess..

Answer (score 2):

In Swift you could use two designated initializers

```
class AwesomePlace{

    init(place:FromPlace){
        // write place.id or place.name here 
    }

    init(place:ToPlace){
        // write place.id or place.name here 
    }
}
```

When you instantiate it like this,
`let myPlace = AwesomePlace(place:somePlace)`
 only the relevant initializer will get called.

Comment: Yeah, this is the last option I'd want to go with though.. My example is very simple compared to what I'm really facing. There are at least 5 different `Place`-variants, and each of them contain a buttload of variables. I'd have to write 5 loooong and identical inits :(

Answer (score 1):

In order to print `FromPlace` and `ToPlace` variables within `init` using a `FromPlaceOrToPlace` parameter, you should be able to check for `FromPlaceOrToPlace`’s type, cast it and unwrap it to that type like so:

```
init(place:FromPlaceOrToPlace){
    if let fromPlace = place as? FromPlace {
        print(fromPlace.name)
        print(fromPlace.id)
    } else if let toPlace = place as? ToPlace {
        print(toPlace.name)
        print(toPlace.id)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is kinda like what I'd normally do, but my goal here is to *not have to do that*. The example in my question was severely simplified. There are at least 5 different variants of `Place`, each of them having a ton of variables. This solution would result in an initialiser with over 200 lines in my actual situation :(